# BufferTime for FLVPLayBack

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, flvplayback

I am working with Playing FLVPlayBack Video. i was wondering about best practice to use buffer time and how exactly buffer behaves while video is in play , pause and stop states.

If i set my FLVPlayBack instance buffer time to 30 sec,

Is it contiguously keep 30 secs video in buffer. for e.g if video is on 15 sec , then it will be having upto 45 sec stream in buffer , for 25 it will have 55 sec stream , for 1.10 it have 1.40 sec stream and so on.. ??

do it behave same as of in play  , in pause and stop states . and if behaves diff. then what is the diff.

Thanks 
Meghana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer time indicates how much time it should have downloaded before it starts playing. Once it's started playing it will continue to download your video in the background as fast as it possibly can until it catches up then it will again buffer the same amount specified in the buffer time.

For instance if you have a video that you've set a 1 minute long clip to buffer for 30s and the size of the clip is 50MB's and you're average viewers download speed is about 512 Kb/sec (aka it downloads 1% every second) then the person will finish the 30's before the rest has a had a chance to download so it will re-buffer, but if the clip's size is 5 MB's over the same duration the video will play seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks @bnns for reply..  does this behavior will same in case of pause and stop states of FLVPlayBack ?

Comment: In the case of pause and stop states it will continue to download the file as fast as it can until the file is completely downloaded. It assumes that the end user is planning to resume the playback at a later time.